# Users' timezone issue onYii2 with PostgreSQL

Tags: php, postgresql, yii2, timestamp-with-timezone

I would like to ask for a better approach. I am using Yii2 with PostgreSQL, and set all timestamp fields for all table to `timestamp with timezone` data type.

```
timestamp with time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT now()
```

I have created setting which will be called for every response,

```php
Yii::$app->setTimezone(MallSettings::getSetting('timezone', Yii::$app->session['mall_id']));
```

which will return something like `Asia/Makassar` or `Asia/Jakarta` (it depends on user's setting).

I extend the `\yii\18n\Formatter`, using a class named `ZeedFormatter` below, and make a new function to display the datetime value in user's preferred timezone.

```php
class ZeedFormatter extends \yii\i18n\Formatter
{
    /**
     * Format timestamp with timezone value to user's preferred timezone.
     * (extends the asDatetime() functionality)
     * 
     * @param  [type] $value  [description]
     * @param  [type] $format [description]
     * @return [type]         [description]
     */
    public function asLocaldatetime($value, $format = null)
    {
        $originalDateTime = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s.uO', $value);
        $originalDateTime->setTimezone(new \DateTimeZone(date_default_timezone_get()));

        if ($format === null)
            $format = 'Y-m-d H:i:s.uO';

        $localDateTime = $originalDateTime->format($format);

        return $localDateTime;

    }
}
```

The idea is that whenever I need a 'local' datetime format, I can call it like so:

```
    Yii::$app->formatter->asLocaldatetime('2019-08-29 19:52:21.02886+07');
    // will return 2019-08-29 20:52:21.02886+08 for Asia/Makassar timezone
```

Or, if used inside a `GridView`,

```
       'position',
       'created_at:localdatetime',

       ['class' => 'backend\widgets\ActionColumn'],
```

Can I get this functionality only using Yii2's feature? Or (another option) is calling `created_at AT TIME ZONE 'Asia/Makassar'` from the Psql query? I hope I can get an enlightment. Thank you.

Comment: umm.. cant you set the default timezone according to the logged in user to the `timeZone` property in the config? if you have the user specific timezone saved, sorry if i overlooked anything

Comment: i am talking about this https://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/197/local-time-zones-and-locales#user-login

Comment: I already take that into account by this code snippet : `Yii::$app->setTimezone(MallSettings::getSetting('timezone', Yii::$app->session['mall_id']));`. And I also consider guest users (a user that don't need to login, or for public pages). I don't know if Yii2 already had the very same functionalities without any new extension or customized code. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My (another) approach is to keep using the `asDatetime()` function.

I just realized that I need to remove / comment the `timezone` from config file. If the value is set there, no matter how I set the timezone at other place, Yii always gets the value from the config file (`common/config/main.php`) if we are using the `asDatetime` formatter.

```
    'components' => [
        'formatter' => [
            // 'class' => '\common\modules\ZeedFormatter',
            'locale' => 'id-ID',
            // 'timeZone' => 'Asia/Jakarta',
            'defaultTimeZone' => 'Asia/Jakarta',
            'dateFormat' => 'php:j M Y',
            'decimalSeparator' => ',',
            'thousandSeparator' => '.',
            'currencyCode' => 'Rp ',
            'nullDisplay' => '<em style="color:#d8d8d8">null</em>',
            'numberFormatterOptions' => [
                NumberFormatter::MIN_FRACTION_DIGITS => 0,
                NumberFormatter::MAX_FRACTION_DIGITS => 0,
            ],
        ],
    ]
```

If we need another (or customized) format, we can still use the `ZeedFormatter` as above and add some desired functions. For example :

```
    public function asMyformat($value)
    {
        $timestamp = strtotime($value);
        $fmt = new \IntlDateFormatter('id-ID', \IntlDateFormatter::NONE, \IntlDateFormatter::LONG);

        $fmt->setPattern('hh:mm z');// will return something like '09:47 WITA' 

        return $fmt->format($timestamp);
    }
```